# How to prevent gerrit from modifying other commits?

Tags: git, gerrit

Consider the following scenario:

1. Alice makes checkout/cherry-pick of Bob's commit  that is still not submitted to master.
2. Bob pushes new patchset  for this commit. Alice is not aware of it.
3. Alice pushes her new commit based on obsolete version of Bob's commit,  gerrit applies new patchset to Bob's commit as well based on Change-ID, overwriting the latest changes from Bob.

Are there any means in git/gerrit to prevent such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented what I need using git pre-push hook. 
Here is a content of my .git/pre-push file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# A hook script to verify what is about to be pushed.  Called by "git
# push" after it has checked the remote status, but before anything has been
# pushed.  If this script exits with a non-zero status nothing will be pushed.
#
# This hook is called with the following parameters:
#
# $1 -- Name of the remote to which the push is being done
# $2 -- URL to which the push is being done
#
# If pushing without using a named remote those arguments will be equal.
#
# Information about the commits which are being pushed is supplied as lines to
# the standard input in the form:
#
#   <local ref> <local sha1> <remote ref> <remote sha1>

AUTHOR=$(git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT)

while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
    commit_author=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:"%ae" $local_sha)
    #echo $local_ref $local_sha $remote_ref $remote_sha $commit_author
    found=`echo $AUTHOR | grep -c "$commit_author"`

    if [ $found == 0 ]
    then
        echo 
        echo "REJECTED by local pre-push hook:"
        echo "You are trying to push some other's commit: $local_sha $commit_author"
        echo "Use --no-verify if you are sure this is not an error" 
        exit -1
    fi        
done
echo "Local pre-push verify passed ok"
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the "Forge Author" default permission:

> Normally Gerrit requires the author and the committer identity lines
>   in a Git commit object (or tagger line in an annotated tag) to match
>   one of the registered email addresses of the uploading user. This
>   permission allows users to bypass parts of that validation, which may
>   be necessary when mirroring changes from an upstream project.
>
> Permits the use of an unverified author line in commit objects. This can be useful when applying patches received by email from 3rd
>   parties, when cherry-picking changes written by others across
>   branches, or when amending someone else’s commit to fix up a minor
>   problem before submitting.
>
> By default this is granted to Registered Users in all projects, but a site administrator may disable it if verified authorship is
>   required.

More info: https://gerrit.cpqd.com.br/Documentation/access-control.html#category_forge_author

Comment: Thank you. It sounds reasonable, but it's pretty hard  to make such a big  server-wide changes in organization with 1000+ engineers. My hope was to have some kind of pre-commit hooks for it or something else user/small team specific

Comment: It's true, on the other hand, it's possible to set the permission only for some specific repositories (projects) used for some specific users/teams.